# Magento 1.9.2.4 - Cron.php problem with update

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, php, price, cron

I created a new web site with Magento 1.9.2.4. The old web site is with Magento 1.7. The old website have this problem...it's not always possible see discounted prices if i do not reloading cron.php every time. Now my question is this. This bug that i have with Magento 1.7, with Magento 1.9.2.4 yet it exists or has been fixed? Or it can be due to a problem of my magento? In this last case, how can i do?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Magento **does need** cron to be properly configured & running. I don't know exactly what version was the first to require this, but I can't remember any Magento project we've developed during last years without cron running in the hosting

Just one explicit example, apart from catalogrule daily refresh (which you're reporting, but can be done through backoffice): mail orders in Magento 1.9 are sent (only) via cron

Comment: Ok. I understand man. But i don't know because in Magento 1.7 discount prices some moments they are not visible to the public. After performing the address www.mysite.it/cron.php discounted prices are visible again. Why this in your opinion? Thanks.

Comment: Catalogrule supports date fields, because of that it needs to refresh (at least) daily. If not, how could Magento know if a catalogrule is still valid? :)